# Angular 8 - why window.scroll is not working on life cycle hook ngOnchanges()?

Tags: angular

I create a directive with Angular 8 as example below:

```
Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomName]'
})
export class CustomNameDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() type: string;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    if (changes.type && changes.type.currentValue) {
      window.scroll({
        top: element.offsetTop,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The code above is not working for window.scroll to position, but when I setTimeout() then it's work fine.

```
Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomName]'
})
export class CustomNameDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() type: string;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    if (changes.type && changes.type.currentValue) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.scroll({
          top: element.offsetTop,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please explain for me why? Is there some things magic here?

Thanks!

Comment: You must have something else going on, it works fine without the `setTimeout`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpbsj6

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to scroll to the position of the element in case the type has changed.
in that case, the following code will do so in a more angular way.

```
Directive({
    selector: '[appCustomName]'
})
export class CustomNameDirective {
    @Input() set type(_type: string) {
        window.scroll({
            top: this.elementRef.offsetTop,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        })
    }

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
}
```